# Restrict Phone numbers with pattern like 0123456789, 8888888888, 9999999999, etc

Tags: php, validation

I need to restrict phone numbers with patterns like:

```
0123456789, 
1111111111, 
2222222222, 
3333333333, 
4444444444, 
etc.
```

I am trying to do it in PHP.

So far i came up with creating an array and searching in it to restrict that mobile no.

Is there any better way to do the same?

Maybe a regex or maybe in javascript.

Comment: So you want to prevent users in typing phone numbers which are "too special"? No, **don't** do that.

Comment: Unless you want to perform pattern detection (i.e. all ascending, all descending, all the same), doing an array lookup is exactly what you would need to do.

Comment: @AlvinWong: if I may, why not?

Comment: If people will not want to reveal their phone number, they will work around any of your blacklists (I would google some number) or get angry and close the tab with your website.

Comment: If you are trying to **validate** phone numbers, look for official format spec (check for check digits, region codes, etc.). If you are trying to **verify** phone numbers, make a voice call.

Comment: Check this answer to a related problem (password complexity), showing that an algorithm is not that easy to implement: http://serverfault.com/questions/300888/how-is-io-6-9001jiaiua121698aa-too-simplistic-systematic

Comment: @ring0 Of course, phone numbers can only be obviously wrong in a few ways :)

Answer (score 2):

If you need to block specific phone numbers, you could do this:

```
$numberToTest = [...]; // this is your user input number to test

$notAllowed = array(
  '0123456789',
  '1111111111',
  '2222222222',
  // and so on
);

if(in_array($numberToTest, $notAllowed)) {
  // NOT VALID
}
else {
  // VALID
}
```

to match all numbers like 1111111111, 2222222222, etc you could do this:

```
if(preg_match('/^(\d)\1{9}$/', $numberToTest)) {
  // NOT VALID
}
else {
  // VALID
}
```

Comment: Because it wasn't the latter.

Comment: Your updated code is basically what OP already thought of, i.e. doing an array lookup.

Comment: @Jack: I think, in fact, that it would be the best choice

Comment: Wow 3 upvotes... people are not really demanding nowadays... (sorry no pun intended, but I wouldn't have dared an answer that simple). It would take a few lines to code the sequences recognition shown in your answer - that would be easily extendable (eg code for [0..9], x{10}, reverse...)

Comment: @ring0: What would be the problem if it is simple, but at the same time solves the problem?

Comment: Agreed, I'm all for simple solutions. But considering the question, and how it contains the array already, I was expecting a more juicy answer - just my opinion based on disappointment. But anyway, some readers like it as it is, good for you!

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to keep updating a long array of numbers to check against like you mention yourself you basically want to do *pattern detection* / *pattern recognition*.

This can be everything from trivial to very complicated depending on your previous knowledge.

A small start can be found here... But there are tons of very thick books on the subject ;)

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pattern_recognition

So the "easiest" way is probably to use an array look up. The downside is that you must know every single number you wish to blacklist beforehand. A middle way would be to have an array of *regexps* of invalid formats that you check against instead of having the actual numbers in the array.

So you could have regexps covering things like

- Numbers to short
- Numbers to long
- Numbers with only the same digits

etc

Depending on available systems and geographical location it might actually be possible to do some kind of look up against some known database of numbers. But that could lead to false positives for unlisted numbers.

For a global, dynamic, working system keeping a look up array and doing look ups against databases could both prove to become very hard to handle since the number of known data sources to keep working support for might grow to large to handle.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript with regexp. isRestricted is set to true when the number is in restricted list:

```
var number = "0123456789";
var isRestricted = number.match( /0123456789|1111111111|2222222222|3333333333|4444444444/g ) != null;
```

I'm sure regexps works with PHP pretty much the same way using [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php).